# Dummy GPU for DAG size issue?

Tags: gpu

I know there is a reg hack that allows you to assign PC memory to Dedicated Video Memory of integrated grahics cards. My question is: Can I in some way use the intel IGPU as a dummy card with enough assigned dedicated video memory so I can continue mining using a 4GB card.